# Get row values with column names in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table :

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PAUL | OLSAN | 54 |
| LAURA | HINKLE | 32 |

I have to create a documentation for each case so I need the details something like this:

(eventually I wanna copy each case details and then write the analysis of it , writing each detail one at a time  will take a lot of time )

FIRST_NAME : PAUL 
LAST_NAME : OLSAN
ID :54
FIRST_NAME :LAURA
LAST_NAME : HINKLE
ID :32

Comment: Couldn't read the post. So converted question to lower case. Now I can see clearly ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: @Shouhaddo, have you done any research or tried to solve this?

Comment: @JoeFerndz I have been searching about it , but couldn't get a proper solution for it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
_ = [print(f'{i.to_string()}\n') for idx, i in df.iterrows()]
```

Output:

```
FIRST_NAME     PAUL
LAST_NAME     OLSAN
id               54

FIRST_NAME     LAURA
LAST_NAME     HINKLE
id                32
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also stack them up as column name and value. Then print them as follows:

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
for a, b in df1.to_numpy():
    print (f'{a}: {b}')

FIRST_NAME: PAUL
LAST_NAME: OLSAN
id: 54
FIRST_NAME: LAURA
LAST_NAME: HINKLE
id: 32
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'First_Name':['Pual','Laura','Mike',], 'Last_Name': ['Olsan', 'Hinkle' ,'Doe'], 'ID': [7,8,9]})


for i,j in df.iterrows():
    print(i,j)
```

[image]

Comment: i think OP wanted a bit more cleaner solution without the dtype and other items